# change state in Grandparent Component with button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child, setstate

Hello i'm new on react and have to do a Tutorial where i have to change the state of the Child Component with a button onClick function. 
currently i'm use a button in my Parent component to do it and it works but now i have to use call this button in other child components and not directly in the Parent to restart my Tutorial.

but i dont know how i can do it.
ill happy about every suggestion.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      run: this.props.run,
      stepIndex: this.props.stepIndex
    }
  }


 componentWillReceiveProps (props) {
    this.setState({ run: props.run, stepIndex: props.stepIndex })
  }

callback = (tour) => {
    const { action, index, type } = tour

    // if you delete  action === 'skip', the Tutorial will not start on other pages after skipped once.
    if (action === 'close' || action === 'skip' || type === 'tour:end') {
      this.setState({ run: false })
    } else if ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND].includes(type)) {
      this.setState({ stepIndex: index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1) })
    }
  }

 render () {
    let { run, stepIndex, steps } = this.state

    if (this.props.location.pathname === '/') {
      steps = []
      run = false
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname === '/matches/' || this.props.location.pathname.length === '/matches') {
      steps = matchSiteSteps
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.endsWith('/edit/')) {
      steps = matchEditorSteps
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.includes('sequence')) {
      steps = matchSequenceSteps
    } else if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.match('\\d+')) {
      steps = matchSteps
    }

    return (
      <>
        <Joyride
          callback={this.callback}
          run={run}
          stepIndex={stepIndex}
          steps={steps}
          continuous
          disableOverlayClose
          spotlightClicks
          showSkipButton
          locale={{
            back: <span>Zurück</span>,
            last: (<span>Beenden</span>),
            next: (<span>Weiter</span>)
          }}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}



class Parent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      run: true,
      stepIndex: 0,
    }
  }

  handler () {
    this.setState({ run: true, stepIndex: 0 })
  }
render () {
    return (
    //some other stuff
        <RestartButton handler={this.handler} />
        <Tutorial run={this.state.run} stepIndex={this.state.stepIndex} />
    //some other stuff
    )
  }
}



class RestartButton extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <button className='restartButton' onClick={() => this.props.handler()}>click</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't store props in the child component state if `state.run` and `state.stepIndex` are always going to be the same as `props.run` and `props.stepIndex`. Instead you should just use those props directly when you need to use them in the render method. `stepIndex={this.props.stepIndex}` will pass exactly the same values to the Joyride component as setting the child component's `state.stepIndex` equal to `props.stepIndex` and then passing `stepIndex={this.state.stepIndex}`.

If you want to change the value of the parent component's state from a child component, you can pass the handler method (bound to the parent component) through as many layers of components as you want, or to as many different children as you want.

```
class Tutorial extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          <>
            <RestartButton handler={this.props.handler}/>
            <Joyride
              callback={this.callback}
              run={this.props.run}
              stepIndex = {this.props.stepIndex}
              steps={steps}
              continuous
              disableOverlayClose
              spotlightClicks
              showSkipButton
              locale={{
                back: < span > Zurück < /span>,
                last: ( < span > Beenden < /span>),
                next: ( < span > Weiter < /span>)
              }}
            />
          </>
        )
    }
}



class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      run: true,
      stepIndex: 0,
    }
  }

  handler() {
    this.setState({run: true, stepIndex: 0})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tutorial
        run={this.state.run}
        stepIndex={this.state.stepIndex}
      />
    )
  }
}



class RestartButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className='restartButton'
        onClick={() => this.props.handler()}
      > click </button>
    )
  }
}
```

(Also, [componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) and you should use componentDidUpdate instead, if you do need to do something on component update).

Comment: thank you but when i delete the states in my child component my callback function doesn't work in the callback he will set the state run: false if i close,skip or finish the joyride tour. i have added the callback to my question so you can look at it :)

Comment: Even if you keep the state in the child component, you you can still set parent component state by passing the handler through the props of multiple levels of children.

Comment: But regarding the callback, can you update the parent component state in the callback rather than the child component state, by passing handlers to set the parent state through props? Setting child component state both internally and when props update is somewhat of an antipattern in React; it's likely to get difficult to maintain so it's better if you can keep it to a single source of truth.

Comment: now i have the problem that in the callback is an else if with `else if ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND].includes(type)) {
      this.setState({ stepIndex: index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1) })
    }` and in the Parent component index, action and ACTIONS doesnt exist do you know how to handle this ?

Comment: nevermind i have handled it. thank you for helping me out :)